# How to Update the bool Property based on Button Visibility in DataGridColumnHeader Style

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, datagrid, datatrigger

I'm having filter Icon style implemented for the Target Type = DataGridColumnHeader and I attached the Style in DataGrid.

My Requirement is to Update the ViewModel `bool Property` `HasFilterIcon` to `true` if any one of the `button` within the `DataGridColumnHeader` gets the `visibility visible` otherwise `false`

My XAML Style is

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridColumnHeader}" x:Key="DataGridElementStyle">
   <Setter Property="Template">
      <Setter.Value>
          <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type DataGridColumnHeader}">
              <Button Name="autofilter" Command="{Binding Path=DataContext.FilterPopUpCommand, 
                                  RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, 
                                                  AncestorType={x:Type Window}}}">
                  <Button.CommandParameter>
                      <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource MultiValueConverterKey}">
                          <Binding RelativeSource="{ RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, 
                                                     AncestorType={x:Type cust:DataGrid}}" />
                          <Binding Path="Column" 
                                   RelativeSource="{RelativeSource Mode=TemplatedParent}" />
                      </MultiBinding>
                  </Button.CommandParameter>
              </Button>
              <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <MultiTrigger>
                        <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                            <Condition Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True"></Condition>
                        </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                        <Setter TargetName="autofilter" Property="Visibility" Value="Visible"/>
                    </MultiTrigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
          </ControlTemplate>
      </Setter.Value>
   </Setter>
</Style>
```

My XAML DataGrid is

```
<DataGrid Name="PassengerGrid" AutoGenerateColumns="False"  ColumnHeaderStyle="{StaticResource FilterDataGridColumnHeader}">
     <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding CustomVisitTime}"  Header="Visit Time" CanUserSort="true" Width="90" ElementStyle="{StaticResource DataGridElementStyle}""/>
     <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding PassengerName}"  Header="Passenger Name" CanUserSort="true" Width="90" ElementStyle="{StaticResource DataGridElementStyle}""/>
</DataGrid>
```

The Property which I need to Update is

```
private bool _hasFilterIcon = false;
public bool HasFilterIcon
{
    get { return _hasFilterIcon; }
    set
    {
        _hasFilterIcon = value;
        OnPropertyChanged();
    }
}
```

If any of the Column Header Button gets the `Visibility Visible`, then I need to change the value of the `HasFilterIcon` to `true` otherwise `false`. Kindly assist me.

> Note: The Style has N number of buttons, out of N I have to check is
>   there is any one of the button is Visible...

Answer (score 0):

use `BooleanToVisibilityConverter` present in `System.Window.Control` namespace. Just declate it as below and use in in the binding(in page/window resources).

```
<BooleanToVisibilityConverter x:Key="BooleanToVisibilityConverter" />
```

**Binding is as below:(Mode OneWayToSource to reflect back to property)**

```
Visibility="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type DataGrid}},Path=HasFilterIcon,Converter={StaticResource BooleanToVisibilityConverter},Mode=OneWayToSource}"
```

**UPDATE**

> As there is no clean way in XAML/WPF to do this(only clean way is to create separate
>   properties to separate button's visibility)

give it a try

**1.Create your property like this:**

```
private AllButtonVisibility visible = new AllButtonVisibility();

    public AllButtonVisibility Visible
    {
        get { return visible; }
        set 
        { 
            visible = value;
            RaiseChange("Visible");
        }
    }

    public class AllButtonVisibility
    {
        public bool AllButtonVisible { get; set; }
    }
```

**2. Sample XAML:**

```
 <Window.Resources>
    <local:MyMultivalueConverter x:Key="MyMultivalueConverter" />
</Window.Resources>

<ContentControl Width="0">
        <ContentControl.Content>
            <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource MyMultivalueConverter}">
            <Binding ElementName="dataGrid" />
            <Binding Path="Visible"  />
             <Binding ElementName="dataGrid" Path="ActualHeight" />
            </MultiBinding>
        </ContentControl.Content>
    </ContentControl>
</StackPanel>
```

**3. Converter:**

```
public class MyMultivalueConverter : IMultiValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        List<DataGridColumnHeader> columnHeaders = GetVisualChildCollection<DataGridColumnHeader>(values[0] as DependencyObject);
        var AllButtonVisibility = values[1] as AllButtonVisibility;
        foreach (DataGridColumnHeader dataGridColumnHeader in columnHeaders)
        {               
            AllButtonVisibility.AllButtonVisible = dataGridColumnHeader.Visibility == Visibility.Visible;
            if (AllButtonVisibility.AllButtonVisible)
                return Binding.DoNothing;
        }
        return Binding.DoNothing;
    }

    public List<T> GetVisualChildCollection<T>(object parent) where T : Visual
    {
        List<T> visualCollection = new List<T>();
        GetVisualChildCollection(parent as DependencyObject, visualCollection);
        return visualCollection;
    }

    private void GetVisualChildCollection<T>(DependencyObject parent, List<T> visualCollection) where T : Visual
    {
        int count = VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(parent);
        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
        {
            DependencyObject child = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(parent, i);
            if (child is T)
            {
                visualCollection.Add(child as T);
            }
            else if (child != null)
            {
                GetVisualChildCollection(child, visualCollection);
            }
        }
    }

    public object[] ConvertBack(object value, Type[] targetTypes, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

**Cause In the what are we if not PROGRAMMERS. :)**

Comment: How can I know whether any of the button is visible or not? Conversion is not an issue. Kindly assist me...

Comment: The Style has N number of buttons, out of N I have to check is there is any one of the button is Visible...

Comment: @B.Balamanigandan use mode OneWayToSource. then if any button gets visibilty=visible your HasFilterIcon will set to true.

Comment: the rest of the button has the visibility Collapsed, so it sets the HasFilterIcon to false.

Comment: @B.Balamanigandan can the visibility of buttons keep changing during the app run time?

Comment: @B.Balamanigandan can the visibility of buttons keep changing during the app run time? or they just initialize once

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/103173/discussion-between-kylo-ren-and-b-balamanigandan).

Comment: @B.Balamanigandan you never got back to me in the chat so that i could finish the answer. Can you answer that now?

Comment: @B.Balamanigandan can't wait any more so updating my answer based on assumption that button's visibility can keep changing. So complex way. :(

Comment: You are used the Compile Time Buttons (i.e., In the Design Time you predefined the button). So, it is easy. Now, we are taking about Style of DataGridColumnHeader, within the style we are having Button, We don't predict, the number of button, we can't bind as like your code. first understand the scenario please.

Comment: @B.Balamanigandan Can't you pass the your grid in the converter and then iterate the headers?

Comment: @B.Balamanigandan and can you give me answer of my question that "is the visibility of buttons can keep changing through the app runtime". I can give you much simpler answer than.

Comment: @B.Balamanigandan you are probably new to WPF. try my updated code now. just pass the grid in converter and iterate on the column headers. hope this will suffice.

Comment: Passing the Entire Gird will degrade the performance... Your Approach is not correct. I find out the easiest way... No Problem... Thanks for your contribution.

Comment: @B.Balamanigandan what are you talking about? "passing the grid will degrade the performance". grid is not a value type that passing that will cause performance issue.

Comment: just let me know too, when you'll find your solution